# Gmail API: How to move a draft into INBOX, like we can do in Gmail UI

Tags: gmail, gmail-api

The [Gmail API docs](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/labels#applying_labels_to_messages_and_threads) states that

> Messages and threads can have multiple labels associated with them; however, ***draft messages cannot have labels applied to them.***

However, we can move a draft to inbox using Gmail web UI.

I would like to do the same thing using API. How can this be done?

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, inbox is a tag, a special default tag. The Gmail API can't add a tag to the draft. But, you can add a feature request to make them allow this to work anyway: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=191602&template=824107

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I'm wondering why things that can be done on the web UI cannot be done by API...

Comment: They didn't take in account every feature, so that's why they have that form up. : )

Comment: Update the message and add the label https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/reference/rest/v1/users.messages/modify

Comment: How are you moving the draft to inbox via the UI?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @DalmTo, I found a solution as below.

```py
message = email.mime.text.MIMEText("This is the body")
message['to'] = "to@example.com"
message['from'] = "to@subject.com"
message['subject'] = "Test draft"
payload1 = {"message": {
    "raw": base64.urlsafe_b64encode(message.as_bytes()).decode("utf-8"),
    # "labelIds": ["INBOX"]  # This will cause an error
    }}
res1 = google.post("/gmail/v1/users/me/drafts", json=payload1)
    
payload2 = {"addLabelIds": ["INBOX"], "removeLabelIds":[]}
thread_id = res1.json()["message"]["threadId"]
res2 = google.post(f"/gmail/v1/users/me/threads/{thread_id}/modify", json=payload2)
# Or (both works)
# message_id = res1.json()["message"]["id"]
# res2 = google.post(f"/gmail/v1/users/me/messages/{thread_id}/modify", json=payload2)
```